# WCF Rest service first send response then save file in local folder

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

In WCF Rest Service, i want to save file asynchronously in .Net frame work 3.5. First i received file from remote server.I want to send response to mobile device then store file in local directory.

Comment: You told us what you want. Once you *do* it and you encounter problems, come here with your specific problem and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: thanks for reply, i explain as follows

Comment: I created on WCF Rest Service. this will get request from Mobile then it create request to Remote server we will get receive the file with file properties as json. i want to save copy of file in to my server directory. then send the response.
but i need,
Example code:

FetchList = objRequest.Fetch(test,key,auth, packid);
SaveFile(FetchList); ////i dont want to wait for file save. first i want to send response then save the file.
Return FetchList;

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? What happens if you cannot save the file, how to send an error back to the user if he already got a response?

Comment: Please find the picture.
https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/d2d6586acfad084b92062894170ff12b20141006064700/f77aeba40dec02bb7c359ed16b88c54920141006064700/e201b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about success of storing the file in your local directory, you can use threads.

The method which is receiving WCF requests can create a thread this way:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => saveFile(args));
t.Start();
```

This thread will execute until its end, even if meantime your WCF service concluded its response.

Please note that the *saveFile()* method is the one which is saving data to file. Make sure that it is not referencing any variables of your WCF service (I suggest you to make *saveFile()* as a static method and pass the data which should be saved as its parameters).